# Why cannot I execute command in an Android phone

Tags: android, linux

I cross-compiled [findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) and generated the program file *find* for Android. I pushed the file *find*  to an Android phone. When I executed the command *find* in the directory where the file *find* is, I got errors as below:

```
sh: find: No such file or directory
sh: ./find: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your command `find` tries to execute the binary in that directory. Go into directory where the binary is located and try running `./find`.

Comment: That means the file does not exist. Double-check you are in the right directory and that the file is present.

Comment: I am sure the file exists. I have tried different directories but I always failed.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with shell commands, but you can check the directory contents with program `ls`. If you do not see your file in the output that means it's not in that directory. It is impossible that the file is present when you get that error when trying to run it.

Comment: I understand it now.  I compiled it with dynamically linked libraries. But the Android phone does have the needed libraries. When I compiled it with statically linked libraries, it worked.